# Adding a nilable variable to a non-nilable array

Tags: crystal-lang

I have a string array named `current_todos` and am trying to add a variable of type `(String | Nil)` named `new_task` by doing the following:

```
current_todos << new_task if typeof(new_task) == String
```

I get the error `Error: no overload matches 'Array(String)#<<' with type (String | Nil)`.

How can I add a nilable string to `current_todos` after doing a type check?

Edit: here is the full code:

```
require "option_parser"

current_todos = [
    "Laundry",
    "Walk dog",
    "Sing in shower"
]

new_task = nil

OptionParser.parse do |parser|
    parser.banner = "Welcome to my todo app!"

    parser.on "-a TASK", "--add TASK", "Type a new task" do |task|
        new_task = task
    end
    
    parser.on "-h", "--help" do
        puts parser
        exit
    end
end

current_todos << new_task if typeof(new_task) == String

current_todos.each do |todo|
    puts todo
end
```

Comment: you need to use `.nil?` or `.is_a?` to check the type in this context.

Answer (score 1):

If `new_task` is of type `String|Nil`, you can test if it is non-nil. Then the compiler will know that it is a string. That here should work:

```
current_todos << new_task if new_task
```

Another way that the compiler will understand, which is closer to your original code, is to use [`is_a?`](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/1.5/syntax_and_semantics/is_a.html):

```
current_todos << new_task if new_task.is_a?(String)
```

Comment: Both seem to still return `Error: no overload matches 'Array(String)#<<' with type (String | Nil)`

I'll update my post with the full code.

Comment: Looks like you were correct with the code I initially gave. The reason it wasn't working for me was because I was assigning `new_task` inside a parser `.on` function.

Answer (score 1):

`typeof(var)` gives the *compile time* type, not the type at runtime. For example:

```
def check_type(var : String?)
  puts typeof(var)
  puts var.class
  puts var.is_a? String
  puts var.is_a? Nil
  puts var.nil?
end

check_type(gets)
```

If you give input, it will print:

```
(String | Nil)
String
true
false
false
```

If you don't give input (`gets` returns `nil`) then it will print:

```
(String | Nil)
Nil
false
true
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the reason something like `current_todos << new_task if new_task.is_a?(String)` doesn't work is because the new assignment of `new_task` happens within the `.on` function of the parser. Since the compiler doesn't know when/if this is called as it is inside a closure, it resorts to `nil`.

To force it to work I would need to use `.not_nil!`

Comment: Yes, because the variable is closued, the compiler can't be sure that both times you refer to `new_task` in that expression, the value is identical. There is a chance it may have been changed in between. A better solution than `.not_nil!` is to assign to a (non-closured) local variable: `if t = new_task; current_todos << t; end`.
An alternative could be `.try`: `new_task.try { |t| current_todos << t }`.